# Run useQuery for each segment of a FlatList - React Native Apollo

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, graphql, apollo

I have a screen in my React Native app where I am rendering a list of friends using the FlatList component.

While listing these friends, I'm trying to run a graphQl query for each friend where I find how many events the user and that friend has attended.

This query requires both the user's email and the friend's email, so it has to be run for each segment of the FlatList.

However, because I have a query to initially load the list of friends, it won't let me do it.

Is there a way to run useQuery multiple times without breaking the hook laws?

This is the query to load the list initially (get the data for the flatlist):

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(mygql.peaInfo , {variables: {email: email}}, {
  fetchPolicy:"cache-and-network"
});
```

This is the FlatList segment rendering function that causes the error (I just removed the return for simplicity):

```
const renderVineSegment = (item) => { 
  const { l, e, d } = useQuery(mygql.eventsAttendedTogether , {variables: {myEmail: email, peaEmail: item.item.email}}, {
   fetchPolicy:"cache-and-network"
  });
  let pos = item.item.position;
  return (
    <View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I'm unsure how to get around this. The only way I can think of is to get all the data on the initial query and then filter through it all to find the events that each friend attends with the user. That would be very cumbersome, so i thought there might be a work around.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern for GraphQL - on the query for the View include the event fields from each friend that you're going to need to display. The whole point of graphql is to get the data you need in one network request. If the computations are too expensive then return a small amount of records and ask for more when the user scrolls to near the bottom of the FlatList.

Comment: Right I see. I assumed so regarding the whole idea of being succint using graphQL, that's why I like it. I think I can write an inexpensive request initially and sort through it myself. Thanks for the advice.